# Customizing radio-button in SCSS syntax

Tags: html, css, sass, radio-button

I customized my radio buttons but I wanted to make my code cleaner using SCSS. So I changed my code from CSS to SCSS but a problem appeared :

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="test" value="value">
<label>
    <span></span>
    Test radio
</label>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: url(./radio-sprite.svg) -46px 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: 92px 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
    background: url(./radio-sprite.svg) -69px 0px no-repeat;
    background-size: 92px 24px;
}

input[type="radio"]:disabled + label span {
    background: url(./radio-sprite.svg) -22px 0px no-repeat;
    background-size: 92px 24px;
}
```

**SCSS**

```
input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;

    & > label {
        cursor: pointer;

        span {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 24px;
            height: 24px;
            margin-right: $margin-small;
            vertical-align: middle;
            background: url(./app/shared/assets/icons/radiobtn-sprite.svg) -46px 0 no-repeat;
            background-size: 92px 24px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }

    &:checked + label span {
        background: url(./app/shared/assets/icons/radiobtn-sprite.svg) -69px 0px no-repeat;
        background-size: 92px 24px;
    }

    &:disabled + label span  {
        background: url(./app/shared/assets/icons/radiobtn-sprite.svg) -22px 0px no-repeat;
        background-size: 92px 24px;
    }
}
```

When I replaced my CSS with the above SCSS code my buttons disappeared. I can't see what seems to be the problem. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You mean scss to css? Also please provide the HTML code.

Comment: @Chris_00 I mean from CSS to SCSS. I edited question

Comment: Your css code is invalid you can not use `$margin-small` varabile

Comment: Check the background image paths are correct and it is able to retrive the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `+` selector:

```
& + label {
        cursor: pointer;
        span {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 24px;
            height: 24px;
            margin-right: $margin-small;
            vertical-align: middle;
            background: url(./app/shared/assets/icons/radiobtn-sprite.svg) -46px 0 no-repeat;
            background-size: 92px 24px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First your css code is invalid because you can not use variable in css as `$margin-small`

Second I use [convertor](http://css2sass.herokuapp.com/) to do that

```
$margin-small:15px;

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
  + label span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin-right: $margin-small;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: url(./radio-sprite.svg) -46px 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: 92px 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  &:checked + label span {
    background: url(./radio-sprite.svg) -69px 0px no-repeat;
    background-size: 92px 24px;
  }
  &:disabled + label span {
    background: url(./radio-sprite.svg) -22px 0px no-repeat;
    background-size: 92px 24px;
  }
}
```